# Jenkins Scripted Pipeline: sshCommand execution statusCode

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

In my jenkins scripted pipeline one stage I am running a bash script in remote machine. I tried few ways as follows but not coping with requirement :
 - Since I have argument to pass to remote server command to run which `sshScript`  doesn't supports it 
 - `publish over ssh plugin` displays my execCommand in the jenkins logs which I dont want too.

So I use sshPut to put  my bash script on remote server and sshCommand with arguments to run it there. All good , except when I have errors, I need to exit and do some other things. What happens is if there is an error, jenkins jobs exits execute with exception. This can be override by setting `failOnError: false` for sshCommand; but then that Job will never fail at all.

I need that if the sshCommand: exits with an error then I need to do some thing like send slackNotify or so. So is there any thing like `statusCode` or `exit-bhalah` which I can compare it like `!= 0` and do some function ?

I am thinking of something like

```
stage('Deploy'){

// some blocks here

 sshCommand remote: remote, failOnError: false, command: "bash Filescript.sh $ARGS1"

  if (statusCode != 0){
     //do my thing here
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use try-catch:

```
stage('Deploy'){
// some blocks here
  try {  
    sshCommand remote: remote, command: "bash Filescript.sh $ARGS1"
  }
  catch {
    //do my thing here
  }
}
```